Intuition behind a bounding function
I often come across the following function and I want to understand the intuition behind it. It is usually used to bound some other function. My question is: where is this kind of function mostly used? Can you give me some relatively less conservative examples of such a function? For example, the identity map would be an example, but it is quite conservative.
$f: \mathcal{R}_+\cup \{0\}\rightarrow \mathcal{R}_+\cup \{0\}$
$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\infty$.
